# Right form verb

Tags: verbs

What is the correct form of following sentence: We helped him *finsh/finishing/to finish/in finishing* the work. Please help me giving right answere.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage, Md. Zahangir Alam. This site isn't designed simply to give right answers to questions of the "which of these options is correct?" type. You would be more likely to avoid having your question closed as off-topic if you identified the option you think is most probably correct, explained why, and then asked what, if anything, was wrong with your reasoning.

Comment: Please see the answer at the nominated duplicate (written by a professor of English) and the others listed on that question.

Answer (score 0):

We helped him (to) finish the work. The "to" is often considered optional these days, as it is implied by the infinitive of "finish". Personally I prefer to leave it in, as it makes the usage of the verb crystal clear.